# Spring integration, How to use @Transformer to convert from/to JSON?

Tags: json, annotations, spring-integration

My question is how to pass object between SI endpoints?

Almost every example I found is using XML settings, I am using Annotation and don't know how to solve this exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve 'json__TypeId__' in 'javaTypes'.
    at org.springframework.integration.support.json.AbstractJacksonJsonObjectMapper.createJavaType(AbstractJacksonJsonObjectMapper.java:68)
    at org.springframework.integration.support.json.Jackson2JsonObjectMapper.extractJavaType(Jackson2JsonObjectMapper.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.support.json.Jackson2JsonObjectMapper.extractJavaType(Jackson2JsonObjectMapper.java:52)
    at org.springframework.integration.support.json.AbstractJacksonJsonObjectMapper.fromJson(AbstractJacksonJsonObjectMapper.java:61)
    at org.springframework.integration.json.JsonToObjectTransformer.doTransform(JsonToObjectTransformer.java:87)
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.AbstractTransformer.transform(AbstractTransformer.java:33)
    ... 18 more
```

People suggest using xml to fix this, for example

```
<bean class="org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.DefaultClassMapper">
    <property name="defaultType" value="foo.MyObject" />
</bean>
```

But I am using annotation to create transformer to process messages receive from channel, like this

```
    @Bean
    @Transformer(inputChannel="fromTcp", outputChannel="toHandler")
    JsonToObjectTransformer jsonToObjectTransformer() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();       
        JsonObjectMapper<JsonNode, JsonParser> jm = new Jackson2JsonObjectMapper(mapper);
        return new JsonToObjectTransformer(jm);
    }
```

Actually I have no clue how to pass object between SI endpoints. I could only pass String and SI use default serialize to handle String to byte[], and byte[] to String.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The converter needs to know what type to convert to; the error you are getting is because you haven't provided a type so it falls back to looking for a header containing type information.

The equivalent of the xml is:

```
@Bean
@Transformer(inputChannel="fromTcp", outputChannel="toHandler")
JsonToObjectTransformer jsonToObjectTransformer() {
    return new JsonToObjectTransformer(MyObject.class);
}
```

Comment: thanks Gary.
do I use JsonToObjectTransformer on both side? (send/receive)
or there is a ObjectToJsonTransformer?

Comment: Yes; there is an `ObjectToJsonTransformer` - it will also set up the headers with type information in case it's needed on the receiving side.

Comment: Gary, I get it all worked out. thanks. Just want to add more information on this in case someone else ran into this. For jackson lib, if the object passed into channel does not have default constructor, use mapper.addMixIn(target, mixInClass), then use target.class and the mapper as parameters to create JsonToObjectTransformer(MyObject.class, mapper)